# How do you expand an element to fill an Expanders Header?

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, header, expander

I'm trying to expand an element to fill the horizontal space of an `Expander.Header`. I asked a similar question earlier, though I have since realized that the premises of the question was incorrect. Any use of `Grids`, or `DockingPanels` seems to have no effect on the ability for an element to fill the horizontal space of a `Expander.Header`.

Some more digging revealed that the `ContentPresenter` for the header is automatically set to `HorizontalAlignment.Left`. How do I go about changing this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is finding the source xaml for the expander and modify it the way you want, creating your own expander style.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a `ControlTemplate`. See [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms753296(v=vs.85).aspx) You have to override the default template for the `Expander`.

You can declare a template which will affect all `Expander` controls using the following:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Expander">
   ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

Or, you can set the `Template` property in a `Style`.

```
<Style TargetType="Expander">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Expander">
                ...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```